# Migrating to new domain controller on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, migration

I tried to replace my old (only) domain controller on the network. I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 on another computer (the old is 2012 R2, too), connected to the domain, added as domain controller. Both are global catalogs and with the "netdom query fsmo" command I see at each of the 5 roles the new server (I followed the instructions from here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/02/10/step-by-step-migrating-windows-server-2003-fsmo-roles-to-windows-server-2012-r2/). My problem is that when I turn the old computer off, on the new server when I try to open AD users and computers or any other snap-in, it says that it can't find the domain (and basically the whole network stops working). Do I need to move any other thing to make it work?

Comment: Usually stuff like this shows up when there are DNS issues.  The new server you built, what are the DNS servers it is using to resolve names? Do "ipconfig /all" and look at the DNS servers in the list. Does your new server run DNS as well? If so, I'd suggest setting one of the DNS servers to 127.0.0.1, and the other would be another domain controller.

Comment: Yeah, get DNS straightened out, run DCDIAG and fix any errors. Also make sure replication is working.

Comment: Did you demote the old domain controller before turning it off?